# ASP.NET MVC view: Can not put any dynamic parameter inside @Url.Content(@item.l_pdf )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

If I put any direct content link inside `@Url.Content()`, it is working fine.

But, when I tried to put a dynamic variable inside `@Url.Content()`, it is showing an error.

I used markup and code like below:

```
<td> <a href="@Url.Content(@item.l_pdf )">Download File</a> </td>
```

Actually I want to show different PDFs depending on the value. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add another  `@` to refer to your item, just do like this:

```
<td><a href="@Url.Content(item.l_pdf)">Download File</a></td>
```

Tested on MVC 5